# Issue while designing B+Tree template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, b-tree

I'm trying to write a generic C++ implementation of B+Tree. My problem comes from the fact  that there are two kinds of nodes in a B+Tree; the internal nodes, which contain keys and pointers to child nodes, and leaf nodes, which contain keys and values, and pointers in an internal node can either point to other internal nodes, or leaf nodes.
I can't figure how to model such a relationship with templates (I don't want to use casts or virtual classes).

Hope there is a solution to my problem or a better way to implement B+Tree in C++.

Comment: Perhaps an implementation of `std::map` can give you some ideas?

Comment: How would you design it for particular types of key and value? Can you make it work as a non-template? Then just substitute the particular types with template parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
bool mIsInternalPointer;
union {
  InternalNode<T>* mInternalNode;
  LeafNode<T>* mLeafNode;
};
```

This can be somewhat simplified by using `boost::variant` :)

Comment: That's the way I chose to implement it at a first glance, but I expected something a little bit more "templatized". I mean, it seems like a hacky low level trick (not type safe, which is why I like templates); but it sounds like it's the only way to do what I what.

Comment: @fokenrute: using `boost::variant` you would get type safety :)